# Maximal matching that is not a maximum matching

Tags: graph

[image]

**Is above graph maxmial but not maximum?**

I went ahead and got a **maximum**, which is **below**.
[image]

Am I understanding Maximal vs. Maximum correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. The first graph is a maximal matching, because you can not add any more egdes to the solution. The second graph is a maximum matching, because it is (one of) the matching(s) with the highest possible sum of weights. The second graph is also a maximal matching.

Comment: Maximum (cardinality) matching is highest possible number of edges. Highest possible sum of weights is maximum weighted matching.